# How to force a particular property to be deserialized as string instead of number?

Tags: c#, deserialization, system.text.json

I have different backends giving back almost the same JSON data model except for a nested json object with the `id` field which sometimes can be a pure number such as:

```json
{ "something": { "id": 1 } }
```

or a string, such as:

```json
{ "something": { "id": "ex.GUID" } }
```

plus the model is made of nullables, different `System` types and custom classes. And I would like those json numbers `1` to be set as`"1"` always(so the C# class model has the this property as `public string Id { get; set; }`), possibly for that precise property.

Is there any `JsonConverter<T>` or property `[Attribute]` that could handle carefully such parsing/deserialization?

ps: the current `JsonConverter<object>` answers don't seem to handle well(exceptions) such scenario as described above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a custom `JsonConverter<T>` for that.

```
/// taken from https://www.thecodebuzz.com/system-text-json-create-a-stringconverter-json-serialization/

public class StringConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number)
        {
            var stringValue = reader.GetInt32();
            return stringValue.ToString();
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            return reader.GetString();
        }

        throw new System.Text.Json.JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
    }
}
```

and register that in the `JsonSerializerOptions`

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        Converters = { new StringConverter() }, 
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true, 
    };

var jsonA = "{ \"something\": { \"id\": \"ex.GUID\" } }";
var a = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonA, options);

var jsonB = "{ \"something\": { \"id\": 1 } }";
var b = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonB, options);
```

complete example [in this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/koOIrs)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, you can solve this with `object`.

```
using System.Text.Json;

DeserialiseAndPrint("{ \"something\": { \"id\": 1 } }");
DeserialiseAndPrint("{ \"something\": { \"id\": \"ex.GUID\" } }");
DeserialiseAndPrint("{ \"something\": { } }");

void DeserialiseAndPrint(string v)
{
   JsonSerializerOptions options = new (){ PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
   var o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(v, options);
   Console.WriteLine($"{o?.Something?.Id} -> {o?.Something?.IdParsed}");
}

class RootObject
{
    public Something? Something { get; set; }
}

class Something
{
    public object? Id { get; set; }

    public string? IdParsed => Id?.ToString();
}
```

This prints:

```
1 -> 1
ex.GUID -> ex.GUID
 ->
```